# how to add multiple http get methods with id as param?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am writing web API, and have to add `two get method` with `id as parameter`.

1st api method :

```
[Route("{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetItem(int id) {
        // some code
    }
```

2nd api method :

```
[Route("clientid/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetItemByClientID(int id) {
        // some code 
    }
```

ajax call :

```
$http({
       url: 'api/mycontroller/clientid',
       method: 'get',
       params: { id: id }
})
```

but its call 1st api method, so how can I call my second api method ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call 2nd api method,

```
[Route("clientid/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetItemByClientID(int clientId) {
    // some code 
}
```

I made changes in ajax call:

```
$http({
   url: 'api/mycontroller/clientid/id?clientId='+id,
   method: 'get'
})
```

`Route["clientid/{id}"]` make route as `clientid/id` follow with parameter `clientId`

so ajax url is to be like `'api/mycontroller/clientid/id?clientId='+id`

Answer (score 0):

In GET request, instead of passing `params` you can do this:

```
$http({
       url: 'api/mycontroller/clientid?id='+id,
       method: 'get',
})
```

Comment: this is same as passing `params : { id : id }` ,

http call is same for both as `http://localhost/api/mycontroller/clientid?id=1`